# Using Django (+DB), Gunicorn, and Socketio, I cannot access Django database from multiple threads

Tags: django, django-models, socket.io, gunicorn, python-socketio

I'm attempting to set up the traditional Django deployment stack (Django, Gunicorn, NGINX). I am also using socketio, similar to the example in the python-socketio documentation.

Unfortunately, the sockets do not play nice with the Django database.

My code is essentially doing the following:

```
from models import MyModel

sio = sio.connect(async_mode = "eventlet")

@sio.event
def my_message(msg, sid):
   MyModel.create(...)
```

I run gunicorn with the following:

```
gunicorn -k eventlet --preload -w 1 django_socketio.wsgi:application
```

I'm getting an error:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: DatabaseWrapper objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object with alias 'default' was created in thread id 140674673057408 and this is thread id 140674672989376.
```

Essentially, the socket handler is being called from multiple threads. However, Django's ORM model doesn't support this, so it's throwing an error.

How do I better support the Django ORM being accessed from multiple threads (or alternatively, make django and socketio play nicer together so this is not an issue)?

NOTE: I've seen basically the same issue described [here](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio/discussions/719), but their solution (`--preload`) did not work for me.

EDIT: You can see a minimally working example here: https://github.com/lgnashold/python-socketio-example. It's basically what is in the text of the post.

The full error given this example is:

```
Exception in thread Thread-4 (_handle_event_internal):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/django/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/django/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/django/lib/python3.11/site-packages/socketio/server.py", line 720, in _handle_event_internal
    r = server._trigger_event(data[0], namespace, sid, *data[1:])
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/django/lib/python3.11/site-packages/socketio/server.py", line 745, in _trigger_event
    return self.handlers[namespace][event](*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/python-socketio/examples/server/wsgi/django_socketio/socketio_app/views.py", line 37, in my_event
    MyModel.objects.create(my_field = str(random.random()))
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/django/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/django/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 658, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/django/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 814, in save
    self.save_base(
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/django/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 877, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/django/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1020, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/django/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1061, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/django/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/django/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1805, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/django/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1818, in execute_sql
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/django/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/django/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 330, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/django/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 308, in _cursor
    return self._prepare_cursor(self.create_cursor(name))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/django/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 297, in _prepare_cursor
    self.validate_thread_sharing()
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/django/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 655, in validate_thread_sharing
    raise DatabaseError(
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: DatabaseWrapper objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object with alias 'default' was created in thread id 140700822507520 and this is thread id 140700786628864.
```

Comment: Please update your question indicating where is the error occurring. There has to be at least two threads sharing an object for this error to appear, but you haven't said anything regarding that.

Comment: Also note that the `--preload` suggestion was made by a random person, not the original person who wrote the question. I personally don't see how `--preload` can have any influence in this.

Comment: @MiguelGrinberg Just updated. I too am unsure how there are multiple threads in this case, I think it is potentially something to do with how eventlet interacts the ORM model.